# Matrix A= $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$. Find all 2x2 matrices X so AX = $X^TA$ - 2$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the matrix
A = $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$

Find all 2x2 matrices $X$ such that $AX$ = $X^TA$ - 2$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.
$X^T$ is the transpose of matrix $X$.

My solution is to:

Let X be $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$
and $X^T$ be $\begin{bmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{bmatrix}$

So it would be:

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}a & c\\b & d\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ - 2$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 3\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}c & d\\2a+3c & 2b+3d\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}2c & a+3c\\2d & b+3d\end{bmatrix}$ - $\begin{bmatrix}4 & 6\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}c & d\\2a+3c & 2b+3d\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}2c-4 & a+3c-6\\2d & b+3d\end{bmatrix}$

This would give me the equations:

$2c-4$ = $c$

$a+3c-6$ = $d$

$2a+3c$ = $2d$

$2b+3d$ = $b+3d$

Solving this would yield:
$c=4$ but all the other variables would be cancelled. Am I missing something? What property did I not use?

Comment: "but all other variables would be cancelled" ???????????? We have $2b=b$, so that $b=0$ and $d=a+6$??? Let me check the equations, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obtain the following equations
\begin{align*}
- c + 4 & = 0,\\
- a - 3c + d + 6 & = 0, \\
2a + 3c - 2d & = 0,\\
b & = 0.
\end{align*}
So we have $c=4$ and $b=0$, $d=a+6$, where $a\in K$ is an arbitrary parameter. So our equations agree. The solutions $X$ are given by the following matrices:
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \cr 4 & a+6\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Wouldn't there be a specific matrix that'll fit? I think I need to apply the properties but idk which one.